# Block/Nullify mouse movement/click in C#

Tags: c#, click, mouse

I am writing an application to fully control the mouse click/movement.

For instance, if I have the application running, form fully transparent, fullscreen, then if I click the mouse button, in normal case, it will bring the application in background in focus - I need to stop this from happening (i.e. clicking the button and nothing visible should happen on the screen), as I need to process all the mouse activity and send it out using this application.

I need to allow 2 mouse to act independently, and I am using this as an overlay, creating 2 fake pointers by drawing using C#, whist disabling the real mouse.

Comment: Is your form invisible rather than "fully transparent"?  Making a form transparent rather than just invisible takes some extra work - this is what you need?

Comment: I wouldn't mind it either being transparent or invisible, as long as I can see whatever application is in the background, and when I click on the invisible/transparent part of my application, the mouse doesn't bring the background application into foreground/focus.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called mouse capture - and it can be done it both Windows Forms as well as WPF and WinAPI directly.

Here's [the way to do it in WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171545(VS.80).aspx).

At the WinAPI level you can use the [SetCapture( HWND w )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262(VS.85).aspx) function call.

Comment: Hi,
In here: Here's the way to do it in WinForms. <-- this actually say that "Also, even if the foreground window has captured the mouse, the user can still click another window, bringing it to the foreground", which is not what I want, what I want is that regardless where/when the button is click, the application would still be in focus/foreground.