# Disable Mouse Cursor (Windows 7/10)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, cursor, mouse

I have a touch screen and I want to disable or hide the mouse cursor for all windows screens and not only for my application screen.

How can I do it programmatically with C/C++ or C#? or with command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179197/block-nullify-mouse-movement-click-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, there is `Cursor.Hide()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) in c#.

If you use WPF application, then you have to set the cursor property to `Cursor = Cursors.None;`

Comment: Thank you, but that methods only will disable the cursor on application window. I want to disable/hide the mouse without an application opened.
For example, I want to have a method in a dll to show/hide or enable/disable mouse.

Comment: Oh I see. Then this wiill help - https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/183676-hide-mouse-pointer-bootup.html